# CSCore-Streaming system audio in real time

Tags: audio, websocket, ffmpeg, streaming, cscore

How can I stream the sound card output audio captured by CSCore in real time? Can it be encoded to an MPEG audio stream using a library like FFMpeg and then streamed using WebSockets?